# DirectX9 and Incompatible Texture size

Tags: directx, textures, pow, capability

I'm working with DirectX9 and now I'm having problems with the texture creation.
I'm using the functions CreateTexture and LoadSurfaceFromMemory with D3DFMT_DXT1 compression, I checked the devices caps of my graphic card and D3DPTEXTURECAPS_POW2 and D3DPTEXTURECAPS_NONPOW2CONDITIONAL are off, I think this means that my graphic card have support of NON Power of Two Textures... I can use textures of any sizes.
My problem is the most of the textures are working well (and their sizes aren't power of two), but in some cases don't work, like "1228 x 453", if I resize to "1228 x 452" the texture works well.
What's going on?

Sorry for my English!.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BCn texture formats are block based. The blocks pack pixels into groups of 4x4 elements, so the texture dimension must be aligned on 4 for theses formats.

Comment: +1. [Proof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `The runtime will not allow an application to create a surface using a DXTn format unless the surface dimensions are multiples of 4. This applies to offscreen-plain surfaces, render targets, 2D textures, cube textures, and volume textures.`

Comment: Yeah! you're right, because the texture compression I must convert my textures to multiples of 4.
thanks! I'm saving now a lot of memory.

Comment: This may be a little off context as non power of two textures are mostly for GUI, but do not forget to generate a mipmap chain if the texture is used on a 3D mesh. It is important for performance ( memory bandwidth ) AND quality ( aliasing and moire ).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a graphics card issue. Even if the card claims support for non power of two textures, support is often buggy / limited.

You could pad the texture and use a subtexture, but the best approach is to build a texture atlas (in general you should be doing this anyway to conserve memory bandwidth)

Comment: Absolutely right, but the problem here is another thing. So if he'll try 1228 x 454, it will not work.